# WPF Grid. Установить Margin для всех дочерних элементов

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-grid

Есть ли какой-нибудь встроенный способ задать отступы для всех дочерних элементов элемента управления `Grid`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Хорошего способа нет. Но если ваши элементы не стилизированы и имеют общий тип, может подойти установка общего внутреннего стиля:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="10"/>
        </Style>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <Button Grid.Column="0" Content="First button"/>
    <Button Grid.Column="1" Content="Second button"/>
</Grid>
```

Результат:

[image: результат]

Ещё вариант для случая разнотипных контролов:

```
<Grid Margin="10">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="10"/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Button Grid.Column="0" Content="First button"/>
    <Button Grid.Column="2" Content="Second button"/>
</Grid>
```

Результат:

[image: результат-2]

Comment: Они не имеют общий тип, к сожалению. Поэтому и возник вопрос.

Comment: @RuslanArtamonov: Тогда можно определить несколько стилей, для каждого типа, например. А что у вас за элементы?

Comment: Да выход то я найду, вопрос больше теоретический. Просто странно, что такая возможность не предусмотрена по умолчанию.

Comment: @RuslanArtamonov: Ну, в отличие от `ItemsControl`, `Grid` не предназначен для показа набора «почти одинаковых» элементов. Поэтому и нет возможности задать общий стиль. А если элементы неодинаковые, то обычно общий стиль неприменим. Вот они и не стали заморачиваться.

Comment: Допустим, есть просто форма для ввода. Наполняем ее TextBlock-ами и TextBox-ами. Для них задали Margin, все красиво. Потом заказчик захотел DatePicker, ListBox и т.д. и т.п. Заканчивается это все печально, набором таких вот TargetType. Очень неудобно. Жалко, что не стали заморачиваться)

Comment: @RuslanArtamonov: Тогда можно по-другому. Если элементов много, имеет смысл вставить дополнительные колонки-распорки. Заодно и исчезнет удвоенный интервал между контролами.

Comment: Да, тоже идея, спасибо

Comment: @RuslanArtamonov: Пожалуйста!